# I cannot find the configuration files on PostgreSQL 14.5 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS!

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I read tutorial https://tecadmin.net/postgresql-allow-remote-connections/ . But in reality, I don't see this file. This is my case:

[image]

I did not see file `pg_hba.conf` and `postgres.conf` . How to allow remote connection on PostgreSQL 14.5 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Answer (score 1):

The PostgreSQL binaries for Ubuntu and Debian split the data directory into two parts: the one you are showing, which contains the files that you should never manipulate, and the configuration files somewhere under `/etc`.

In your case, you should find the configuration files in `/etc/postgresql/14/main`.